# Change 'bind' config of Redis server without restarting it

Tags: redis

I'm trying to change my redis 'bind' config without restarting it. [here](http://redis.io/commands/config-set) says that I can do this using CONFIG SET bind "new ips" but when I type that in redis-cli I get following error!

> (error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: bind

Is there anything wrong with the command I'm using, or Redis does not support this config change without a reset?

P.S: If its usefull, "CONFIG GET bind" works fine and returns current config.

Comment: Not a chance. Have to restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently.My Redis instance was already bound to 127.0.0.1 . The only solution I could think of was nating over ip tables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d  <NEW_IP_TO_BIND> --dport 6379 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:6379
```

where < NEW_IP_TO_BIND > is the IP you want to add and 127.0.0.1 the the already configured value of bind

Also in this case because I am using 127.0.0.1 not any other address as destination I had to allow forwarding from the interface of < NEW_IP_TO_BIND>  to local using:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```

(in my case the interface was eth0)

The above is a bit dodgy when it comes to security and should not be considerred as a solution for permanent configuration. 
It could only be ok for temporary migration configuration

Comment: This does not work in clustered Redis. Each node will still be pointing at loopback which will screw up with client operations

Comment: true not meant for cluster mode